# Select column based on another column's value - SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table of rates and terms from which I need to use the term to select the appropriate rate adjustment.  The issue is, each term is its own column as so:

```
term  12mon  24mon  36mon
----- -----  -----  -----
 12     2      4      6
 24     2      4      6
```

I need, for each term, to return the correct adjuster.
Thus for 12 months I would need a "2" and for 24 it would be "4" and so on.  While vastly oversimplified it captures the essence - I need to select a column name in a table based upon the value of another column in the same table.
I'm not able to change the source table.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

case is your friend

```
 case term 
    when 12 then [12mon] 
    when 24 then [24mon] 
    when 36 then [36 mon] 
 end as rate
```

if value of term can be between 12 and 24, etc.   then write it this way (I'm not sure what your logic needs to be, but you get the idea)

```
 case 
    when term < 12 then  0
    when term < 24 then [12mon] 
    when term < 36 then [24mon] 
    when term < 48 then [36mon] 
    else [48mon] 
 end as rate
```

Answer (score 0):

What flavor of SQL is that ?

In most of them you can use `CASE WHEN (predicate) THEN x` statements which you can use to get different columns and then alias it.